# using context with an api call for the root level component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am new to use the react context, but i think how the redux works like, but not getting the proper way.

so i have a component where i will get data from api once i get the data i need to show a loader once data gets load the component

but how i set the value to context and use it.

see the below snippet

```js
class App extends Component{

    componentDidMount(){
        this._fetchData()
    }

    _fetchData = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("http://www.example.com", {method: "GET"})
        const data = await response.json()
        // how can i use context and set the value
    }

    // how should i use a provider to the router so basically i need to get the data every where in the route
    render(){
        return(
            <Router>
            { Object.keys(context.data).length > 0 ?
                <Layout>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/sample" exact component={SampleHomePage} />
                        <Route path="/sample/profile" component={SampleProfile} />
                        <Route path="/sample/about" component={SampleAbout}/>
                    </Switch>
                </Layout>
                : <p>Data Loading </p>}
            </Router>
        )
    }
}


// profile.js

import React from  'react';

const profile = () => {
  //how to get the contex value here
}

export default profile
```

Comment: In this example you wouldn't need context. You can use `setState` in `_fetchData` and consume that state in `render`, e.g. `Object.keys(this.state.data).length > 0`. For details on why and when to use the Context API I'd recommend taking a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html.

Comment: but going forward if i have 10 routes then i need to pass the state data as props to each and every route isn't

Answer (score 0):

Look at this codesandbox and check how i worked with context.

https://codesandbox.io/s/2p0koqr81p

The key is that you need an extra component that will work as the context.
In this case i've just saved the data from the fetch call into the context.

So you have to **provide the updated data** to the context so then you can **consume** it in any component that you want.

I agree with @Joru that maybe is unnessesary to use context in your use case, but im trying to answer the question.

Comment: can you check the codebox is not running giving white screen also, didnt find any sub component and accessing data

Comment: i have updated the question can you let me know how to get the value in the profile component from the context

Comment: The idea iof my example is this: The context stores any value that you want by the MyAppContextProvider like the **value**:
```<MyAppContext.Provider value={this.props}>
        {this.props.children}
</MyAppContext.Provider>
```
Then you can access this data using the ```MyAppContextConsumer```. you just have to wrap the component that you want.